# no login screen after change from lightdm to xdm

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, lxdm

On 12.04 LTS, I typed "apt-get install xdm" - then a window asked if I wanted
lightdm or xdm, and I selected xdm. Then I rebooted but the display only showed,
for a very long time, the word "ubuntu" and orange dots moving over a purple
background. There was no login prompt. I was not able to use key sequences such
as Ctrl-Alt-F1 to Ctrl-Alt-F7 (or Alt-F1 to Alt-F7) to obtain a text terminal.
All of these key sequences were ignored. I rebooted multiple times and this behavior
always occurs. What is the easiest way to obtain login access to the system?

Comment: Press "esc" while the Ubuntu splash screen is showing to see what fails.

Comment: The last two lines are "Starting X display manager xdm [OK]" and "Stopping System V runlevel compatibility [OK]." All of the "[]" are "[OK]." The only part that looks like possibly an error message is "Starting CUPS printing spooler/server [OK]" followed by "could not write bytes: Broken pipe." After showing this output in response to the "esc" key, the system seems hung (or at least I don't know what other keyboard input I should use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to change a 12.04 LTS system from LightDM to xdm by installing the xdm package and then running `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to select xdm apparently does not work.

The failure mode is that a normal boot hangs forever on the "orange dots - purple background" screen, and it is necessary to use recovery mode to access the system. One or both of these other two steps will apparently fix the problem:

- delete the `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` file and/or
- edit the `/etc/init/plymouth-stop.conf` file, locate the line beginning with gdm|kdm and change this line to begin with xdm|gdm|kdm instead.

I most likely will not research this further and most likely will not submit a bug report myself. I do not know whether either of the steps mentioned above is considered a supported or recommended configuration change. Also, I do not know whether use of xdm is considered a supported activity on 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Good point Judy... I had the same issue and I solved reinstalling gdm

Answer (score 2):

Reboot the computer and keep the SHIFT key pressed in order to access the boot options. Select "recovery mode". This should allow you to login in your system again.

Comment: The underlying problem might be a bug in /etc/init/plymouth-stop.conf in which the line that begins with gdm|kdm ought to begin with xdm|gdm|kdm instead. I do not have permission to self-answer, but may try to self-answer after waiting the required number of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem happened to me.

Go to tty1 with Control + Alt + F1.
Then I ran

```
lightdm
```

from there.The login screen appeared this time.Also I will try to apply the fix listed above

edit the `/etc/init/plymouth-stop.conf` file, 
locate the line beginning with `gdm|kdm` and
change this line to begin with `xdm|gdm|kdm` instead.